# How to use array_intersect in one array

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have this array and i want to compare each key items with each other and get similars with array_intersect . I wrote this code but it just compare first 2 key items and i want to compare all of key items.

[image]

```
            $res_arr = array_shift($m);
            foreach($m as $filter){
                $arr = array_intersect($res_arr, $filter);
            }
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example possibly with a input test and the desired output

Comment: as you know, array_intersect needs 2 arrays to compare values and it'll return an array with similar between 2 arrays, now i want to consider each key with it's values as an array and pass it to array_intersect to compare. my desire output ? an array with all similar values between all values.

Comment: In other words, you want only the values that occur under every key of the top level array? I can only assume you want to ignore the empty ones, because they would cause each intersection to be an empty array.

Comment: but you have 2 empty arrays, the intersection with those will be obviously an empty array, so are you sure that you want the intersection of all the array?

Comment: Yes, Exactly! how to do this ?

Comment: is it going to be problem with empty arrays ?!

Comment: I removed empty arrays before adding it to final result, how i can compare them now ?

Comment: You were on the right track for that, but you didn't loop your top level array. You don't need to shift, just loop the array, intersect first two elements and then use the result of that intersection to intersect with the next element and so on until you reach the end of the array.

Comment: how to get the first two elements in top level array loop ?

Comment: foreach ($m as  $arr) {
 
}
$arr gives first key with it's values

Comment: You can get the index as well in a foreach by defining it: `foreach ($m as $index => arr)` or you can use a `for` loop. Then use the index for simple array access.

Comment: still struggling with it, can you please provide me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the intersection of all the arrays inside the initial array, you need to perform the intersection of the elements with the intersection of the previous elements:

```
$arr = [ 
    0=>[...],
    1=>[...],
    2=>[...],
];
$intersection = array_pop($arr);
foreach($arr as $el)
    $intersection = array_intersect($arr, $intersection);

print_r($intersection);
```

Please not that in your example you have 1+ empty array, and so the intersection will be an empty array

Comment: and also don't have any empty array, removed it before adding it to final result